# In Android emulator, Android app installed successfully and shown under Setting -> Apps, but not shown on Apps home screen

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I installed the app and I get the following message

```
------------------------------
[2014-02-17 13:02:42 - Stealth1] Android Launch!
[2014-02-17 13:02:42 - Stealth1] adb is running normally.
[2014-02-17 13:02:42 - Stealth1] No Launcher activity found!
[2014-02-17 13:02:42 - Stealth1] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2014-02-17 13:02:42 - Stealth1] Performing sync
[2014-02-17 13:02:42 - Stealth1] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'Stealth1'
[2014-02-17 13:02:42 - Stealth1] Uploading Stealth1.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-02-17 13:02:42 - Stealth1] Installing Stealth1.apk...
[2014-02-17 13:02:49 - Stealth1] Success!
[2014-02-17 13:02:50 - Stealth1] /Stealth1/bin/Stealth1.apk installed on device
[2014-02-17 13:02:50 - Stealth1] Done!
```

I could find the app installed in emulator under Setting --> Apps. But how should I run the application. I tried running it from eclipse. Still I couldn't run. When I run from command line I get

```
1934 KB/s (288622 bytes in 0.145s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Stealth1.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the LAUNCHER category for your main Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml. Example:

```
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Should it be within application tag or manifest tag or activity tag

Comment: It should be within <activity> HERE </activity>

Comment: It was already there. but I missed `.MAIN`  in `android.intent.action`. But now I get the following error. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840224/how-to-fix-opengl-es-api-issue-in-android-app-emulator